# Dynamically created textbox's value doesnt get updated

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating dynamic rows with this code, but the textbox's value is not getting updated as i type. That is as i type i can see the text in the text box but when i fetch/inspect the value it is empty.

I have tried exploring on this but i couldnt understand what's happening, any clues?

```
$('#add_ans').click(function(){
var rowCount = $('table tbody tr').length + 1;
var rowString = '<tr>\
                    <td><div class="span_5"><span class="badge badge-success">'+rowCount+'</span></div></td>\
                    <td><div class="span3"><input type="text" class="input-large" value="" /></div></td>\
                    <td><div class="span2 pull-right"><b>0</b></div></td>\
                    <td><div class="span2"><button class="btn btn-success" id="vote'+rowCount+'"><b>Vote!</b> <i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i></button></div></td>\
                    <td><div class="span2"><button class="btn btn-info" disabled><b>Reviews</b> <i class="icon-ok-circle"></i></button></div></td>\
                </tr>'
$('tbody').append(rowString);
$('tbody').on("click","#vote"+rowCount,voteOption);
```

});

and the event handler is

```
function voteOption(){            
    var rowCount = $('tr').index($(this).closest('tr'));
    alert(rowCount);
    var ans = $('tr:eq('+rowCount+') .input-large').attr('value');
    alert(ans);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `.attr('value')`

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the `value` attribute in your HTML, so it will remain empty.  Just use `val()` instead of `attr('value')`:

```
var ans = $('tr:eq('+rowCount+') .input-large').val();
```

Alternatively, you can set the `value` attribute in the HTML you're generating, then retrieve it using the approach you are now.

Here's a jsFiddle with it working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/Rjrpy/